# How to list all Block files, Character device files,pipe files,Socket files recursively with pure python codes instead of bash?

Tags: python, file

There are seven file types in linux: Regular files,Directory files,Block file, Character device file,pipe file,Symbolic link file,Socket file.
All the files and direcotries can be listed recursively.

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if  os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root,name)):print(os.path.join(root,name))
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        if  os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root,name)):print(os.path.join(root,name))
```

All links can be listed recursively with python.

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if  os.path.islink(os.path.join(root,name)):print(os.path.join(root,name))
```

How to list all Block files, Character device files,pipe files,Socket files recursively with pure python codes instead of bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `os.walk()` already working there, so the missing piece is using the `os.stat` function and the [`stat` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stat.html#module-stat) to figure out what type each file is.